# Help to understand the use of 'need' in this context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> As long as he didn't leave spots of ink on the sheets, the Dursleys ***need*** never know that he was studying magic by night.

As I understand, '**need**' denotes the sense of "*To be under the necessity of or the obligation to*". I feel '**would**' might fit better for the context. *As long as he didn't leave spots ink on the sheets, the Dursley **would** never know that he was studying magic by night*.

So, how should we understand the use of '**need**' in this context?

-- From Harry Potter.

Comment: In your context, *need* roughly meant *have to*. Dursley never have to know that he was studying magic.

Comment: Would it be any easier for you if it said "never need to know"? The implied meaning is, "there is no need to inform them" or "there is no need for them to find out".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I think I have no problem to understand the meaning. Maybe, I don't quite understand the logic or conventions. As I understand, Harry is trying hard in order not to let the Dursleys know he was studying magic by night. So, he need to make sure he didn't leave any spots of ink on the sheets, otherwise the Dursleys would find out the truth. That's why I think 'would' probably fit in this sentence and 'need' might not fit semantically. I'm not sure if you could understand me. Anyway ...

Comment: @dan: The logic of **as long as....need never know** can seem a little odd, but if you paraphrase **need never know** as "will have no cause to know" the meaning might emerge, understanding "cause" broadly to include "compelling reason".  They have no reason to demand to be informed, and neither will there be any telltale evidence of his activity.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, If I understand it correctly this time, "need never know" denotes two aspects: The Dursleys don't need to know; if they didn't find any telltale evidence, they wouldn't find out; And if we replace 'need' with another word like 'didn't' or 'would', then the sentence would lose the first connotation: "The Dursleys don't need to know;" Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you have it. There is no need or cause for them to know, and they won't find out if there's no evidence.  The first part wouldn't be expressed if you change **need never know** to "would never know".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use *needn't*/*need never + infinitive*/*don't need to* for **absence of necessity** felt by the speaker:

> We needn't put the heating on yet; it's not cold enough.
>
> We don't need to turn on the light; it's 1 p.m.
>
> You need never be lonely again. I'll always be by your side.

Comment: Can you help to explain a bit based on the context I quoted?

Comment: @dan the Dursleys don't have to know about him studying magic by night. There is no need for them to know about it. It's not necessary. He just has to make sure there are no spots of ink left. If there are none, the Dursleys will not find out.

Comment: I'm not sure why it put this way. I still can not get through the logic. Is there anything different if I put: "*As long as he didn't leave spots ink on the sheets, the Dursley **would** never know that he was studying magic by night.*"?

Comment: @dan are you trying to use "would" to describe a past state or to make a conditional sentence?

Comment: I think "as long as" forms a conditional sentence. Is it right? Yes, I tried to make a conditional sentence. But I'm not sure if there is any difference here between a past state and a conditional sentence. Does it really matter?

Comment: @dan yes, and by the way "would" with state verbs is ungrammatical if you mean a past state. So if you are trying to make a real past conditional, it should be "they didn't know", not "wouldn't know". Because it becomes a real past conditional. Another example: "if I didn't do my homework, my mother didn't let me watch TV."

Comment: hmmm.. I'm confused. I think it could be the subjunctive mood. How about these examples: "*What I did was right and if I had done anything less it would have been wrong.;if I come, I'll see him; if I were you, I wouldn't do that*"

Comment: @dan Don't be confused. All your sentences are right. If you want an UNREAL past conditional, use "if had + V3, would have..." And if you want a REAL conditional, use if + PAST SIMPLE, PAST SIMPLE.

Comment: @dan check out my post https://enguroo.com/2018/06/08/conditionals/ and pay close attention to zero conditionals.

Comment: Thanks for that information. But what would be the difference if I replace 'need' with 'would' in this context? That's my main concerns.

Comment: @dan it would be ungrammatical. You can possibly say "If he didn't leave spots of ink on the sheets, the Dursleys never knew..." - real past conditional OR "If he hadn't left spots of ink on the sheets, they would have never known..." - unreal past conditional

Answer (score -1):

It basically means he would "never **need** to know" Similar to the way you would say "need not"